# Concatenating strings in a apandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

Following is an example of string that is a variable of my df:

```
df_final['newa_1'][8395389]
"['Y02T  10/70' 'Y02E  60/00' 'Y02T  90/16' 'Y04S  10/126' 'Y02T  10/7072' 'Y02T  90/12' 'Y02T   90/14']"
```

What I would like to do is to put an "_" within the elements between '' regardless of how many spaces there are. So, in the example above, the output should be something like:

```
"['Y02T_10/70' 'Y02E_60/00' 'Y02T_90/16' 'Y04S_10/126' 'Y02T_10/7072' 'Y02T_90/12' 'Y02T_90/14']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `re` as follows:

```
foo = "['Y02T  10/70' 'Y02E  60/00' 'Y02T  90/16' 'Y04S  10/126' 'Y02T  10/7072' 'Y02T  90/12' 'Y02T   90/14']"

import re

re_whitespace = re.compile(r"\s+")

re_whitespace.sub('_', foo).replace("'_'", "' '")
```

Giving you:

```
"['Y02T_10/70' 'Y02E_60/00' 'Y02T_90/16' 'Y04S_10/126' 'Y02T_10/7072' 'Y02T_90/12' 'Y02T_90/14']"
```

Comment: is it possible to use it within a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Sure, reusing the code would look like: `df['newa_1'].str.replace(re_whitespace, '_').str.replace("'_'", "' '")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex group match and replace:

```py
df["newa_1"].str.replace(r"([^'])(\s+)([^'])", "\\1_\\3", regex=True)

['Y02T_10/70' 'Y02E_60/00' 'Y02T_90/16' 'Y04S_10/126' 'Y02T_10/7072' 'Y02T_90/12' 'Y02T_90/14']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace` function of pandas.

for example:

```py
df_final['newa_1']=df_final['newa_1'].str.replace(" ","_")
```

Comment: The problem is that this command also concatenates the various strings within '': "['Y02T_10/70'_'Y02E_60/00'_'Y02T_90/16'_'Y04S_10/126'_'Y02T_10/7072'_'Y02T_90/12'_'Y02T_90/14']"